# Huyndai sonata 2012 engine misfires

Tags: car, hyundai, misfire, motors, sonata

I have Huyndai sonata 2012 GDI 2.4 cc

The car starts just fine, but after few miles the engine misfires in the same cylinder, and when i stop the engine and run it again, the engine go back to normal without misfiring.

Note: the check lamp is on due to vent solenoid failure. And I have replaced the spark plugs and coils.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is the code you're stating for the EVAP system? Which exact code is it? I don't remember which EVAP the Sonata has (could be vacuum or pressure). If it is a vacuum system and the EVAP isn't working, it might be starving the engine for fuel, though that wouldn't relate to why the misfire is always in the same cylinder. Have you checked the connector to the injector for corrosion? Could also be the injector itself is heating up and causing an issue of not wanting to work correctly. Is the misfire constant once it starts, or is it intermittent?

Comment: The code is P0449

Comment: The misfire is constant once it starts, and the misfire stops when I stop the engine and start it again.